# Map LANGID from Win32_OperatingSystem to C# CultureInfo

Tags: c#, localization

Is it possible to map `LANGID` from [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) to C# `CultureInfo`. Or more specifically the `Locale` property in `Win32_OperatingSystem`?

Here is the description

```
Locale
Data type: string
Access type: Read-only
Qualifiers: MappingStrings ("Win32API|National Language Support Functions|GetLocaleInfo|LOCALE_ILANGUAGE")
```

> Language identifier used by the operating system. A language
>   identifier is a standard international numeric abbreviation for a
>   country/region. Each language has a unique language identifier
>   (LANGID), a 16-bit value that consists of a primary language
>   identifier and a secondary language identifier

I thought that it would map to the LCID parameter of `CultureInfo`, but then I got the value `409` in a report and it made `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid)` throw an exception.

So what's the proper way to get the `CultureInfo` (or anything else that would give me a human name instead of the language code).

Comment: *409* looks too close to *0x409* (standard US English) to be a coincidence. Check your code, and generally, use `GetCultureInfo(string)` since you start with a string.

Comment: @Amit: It's a string yes. But it's `"409"`. But you are right. I converted it from a hex string to an integer. That worked. thanks. You can add it as an answer: `int lcid;
if (int.TryParse(currentValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
    out lcid))
{
    currentValue = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid).Name;
}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the string as a hexadecimal number:

```
int lcid;

if (int.TryParse(currentValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber,
    NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out lcid)) {
  currentValue = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid).Name;
}
```